# MadeLine proto library and add hhvm to php torm

Tags: php, phpstorm, telegram, telegram-bot, hhvm

hi i want to use MadelineProto in my project to automate some activity.I need to join channel which the admin dosen't add me.i heard by madeline it's possible.in the requirement of madeline it said the madeline only work on php7 and  hhvm.my first question is how can I add hhvm to phpstorm??
and my second question is:I wrote this lines

```js
set_include_path(get_include_path().':'.realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/MadelineProto/'));

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$settings = ['app_info' => ['api_id' => 6, 'api_hash' => 'eb06d4abfb49dc3eeb1aeb98ae0f581e']];//it is default api id and hash of madeline

try {
    $MadelineProto = \danog\MadelineProto\Serialization::deserialize('bot.madeline');
} catch (\danog\MadelineProto\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    $MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API($settings);
    $authorization = $MadelineProto->bot_login(readline('my bot token'));
    \danog\MadelineProto\Logger::log([$authorization], \danog\MadelineProto\Logger::NOTICE);
}
```

when i debug this in line 8 it return file doesn't exist and it stucked in line 11.
what should i do?
tnx

Answer (score 0):

On line 11, you're using [readline](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php) to read the token from console.
You probably wanted to hardcode it, so substitute that line with the following line:

`$authorization = $MadelineProto->bot_login('your bot token');`